# how to complete order status automatically after paypal payment received

Tags: order, paypal, autocomplete

we are using paypal payment gateway for payment we want autocomplete order status after payement received how we can complete order status automatically is there any plugin

Comment: Is this Woocommerce? Which PayPal integration are you using? (I can't remember if there's a default one.) But I'd expect they'd all handle the 'payment complete' callback.

Comment: woocommerce default paypal